# Folder Path in .properties file

Tags: java, parsing, properties, path

I was trying to put all the paths(folder paths/urls) in a .properties file, so that if I'm going to change my paths it will be easier. So this is one of the data in my path.properties:

```
path.pvInfoIni=C:\\Palmus-HACMS\\PV\\PvInfo.ini
```

and this is the real directory of the file:

> C:\Palmus-HACMS\PV\PVInfo.ini

this path leads to an .ini file where data are being written.

Here's the code where I call the path:

```
Properties property;
FileInputStream fs;     
fs = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\path.properties");


common.writeIniFileIdentify("PV-ID", PVIDNo); // PsFileAccessorIni.GetInstance().GetValueString(PsFileAccessorIni.PVIDLocation));
common.writeIniFileIdentify("PALMUS-ID", SerialNo);// PsFileAccessorIni.GetInstance().GetValueString(PsFileAccessorIni.PVIDLocation));
common.writeIniFileIdentify("Authentication", "VALID");// PsFileAccessorIni.GetInstance().GetValueString(PsFileAccessorIni.PVIDLocation));

property = new Properties();
property.load(fs);
System.out.println(property.getProperty("path.pvInfoIni"));
String pvId = property.getProperty("PV-ID");
String palmusId = property.getProperty("PALMUS-ID");
System.out.println(pvId);
System.out.println(palmusId);
```

And when I tried to run the program this is the output:

[image]

I'm not sure if it really goes to that path. If so why does the pvId and palmusId is null? I hope someone can help me. I'm just new with this kind of stuffs. Thank you in advance.

P.S.
But when I use this code:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileInputStream("C://Palmus-HACMS/PV/PVInfo.ini"));
String pvId = p.getProperty("PV-ID");
String palmusId = p.getProperty("PALMUS-ID");
System.out.println(pvId);
System.out.println(palmusId);
```

the value of PV-ID and PALMUS-ID is being output.

Comment: change this System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\path.properties"); to absulte path

Comment: You have not defined `PV-ID` & `PALMUS-ID` properties inside `path.properties` file.

Comment: @Jay still don't work Sir.

Comment: @Swaraj but the PV-ID & PALMUS-ID are inside the ini file.

Comment: @KendallH. then why you are reading it from properties file? Ideally, You got path from properties file, then from path read the `.ini` file and then print the values for `PV-ID` & `PALMUS-ID`.

Comment: have you checken if it gets written on the file? I assume that's supposed to get done on the `common.writeIniFileIdentify` lines but its safe to check

Comment: @Swaraj I just want to put the paths & urls on properties file. Is it necessary to define PV-ID & PALMUS-ID on path.properties?

Comment: @RocAràjol yes it gets written on the .ini file.

Comment: @KendallH. Let me clarify your issue. You have one properties file named path.properties. Inside there is path for another file named `PVInfo.ini`.. So there are 2 files, one hold path & other is for PV info. In that case, you have to load path properties file first, read the file. Open second properties instance for .ini with path from first property file and then read Actual PV values.

Comment: @KendallH. see my ans

Answer (score 1):

A `Properties` object can only load the key/value pairs that you have in the properties file nothing more, **it is not capable of loading dynamically** `ini` or `properties` files whose path could be defined as values because for it we have only `String` keys and values nothing more.

If you want to dynamically load also `ini` files, you will need to do it manually using for example [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/).

One way to have everything into your `Properties` instance could be to proceed as next:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("path.properties")) {
    properties.load(is);
}
// Then we load the key/value pairs in the ini file
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(properties.getProperty("path.pvInfoIni"))) {
    Wini wini = new Wini(is);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Profile.Section> entry : wini.entrySet()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> subEntry : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
            // Add the entry of the init file into the properties file
            // using ${section-name}.${key-name} as key and ${value} as value
            properties.put(
                String.format("%s.%s", entry.getKey(), subEntry.getKey()), 
                subEntry.getValue()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to add a prefix corresponding to the name of the section which prevents naming collision, you can  simply replace `String.format("%s.%s", entry.getKey(), subEntry.getKey())` with `subEntry.getKey()` in the code above but I don't personally believe that it is a good idea/practice.

Comment: Oh, so that's how it works Sir. Thank you. So the thing that I want to do is not possible? I still have to manually put the folder path in my code? Cause I also put some urls in path.properties where I will send the value of PV-ID and PALMUS-ID. It doesn't work that way?

Comment: you can leave your path in your properties file as you do, but you will have to get them from your properties file to be able to load the ini files manually, it cannot be done automatically by the `Properties` object

Comment: Thank you so much for the information Sir! But if I'm going to put a http://localhost:8080/sample/website in my path.properties then call it as "path.url" to call it and send data to it, it will not work? Thank you for guiding me Sir!

Comment: simply because you have a prefix to consider which is the section's name please read properly the comments in my answer. Assuming that `PV-ID` is in the section `foo`, the name of the key will then be `foo.PV-ID`

Comment: Already add path., but the only value I'm getting is "PV-ID" cause in my path.properties I have path.PV-ID=PV-ID, but the variable PV-ID should have the same value on what's in the ini file. Please be patient with me. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the late response Sir, here's what inside my ini file: 
Authentication=VALID
PALMUS-ID=733640
PV-ID=PVID-0000007

Comment: If you have no section defined then the key will be `?.PV-ID`

Comment: Just 'PV-ID' Sir.

Comment: Thank you for your patience Sir. I edit the code. The values are being output, but the outputs are not consistent. It's output is 16, sometimes the first 10 is null value followed by the PV-ID & PALMUS-ID, and sometimes it's 3 null value followed by PALMUS-ID then null then PV-ID. Why is that? Thank you so much for your help Sir!

Comment: put the content of your code and the content of your files properties and ini into your question to allow us to reproduce because so far it is hard to help anyhow

Comment: Here's my java class http://pastie.org/10946628 and here's my path.properties http://pastie.org/private/udf6cwichganhxdtxyq Thank you so much Sir.

Comment: what about the content of `PVInfo.ini`?

Comment: simply do `System.out.println(properties)` to see its content

Comment: Here's what's in PVInfo.ini Sir: http://pastie.org/private/afavii8pmacqil2pmxb5iw

Comment: it is not a valid `ini`file because there is no section

Comment: anyway with the code change proposed above, it worked on my side with this `ini`file so I don't see how I can help any further sorry

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Sir. :) Is the java class code that I send to you has no problem? If so why does it out put 16 data? Thank you for all your help Sir.

Comment: probably because of `common.writeIniFileIdentify` which (I guess) modifies your ini file so if you call your method `Ps_Sample_Apl_Java_NotifyResult_Identify` multiple times you get the last values only

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you Sir. Sorry Sir but I have another question, I want to use `path.hacmsAuthorizePerson` from my `path.properties` in my controller to call the localhost url, so this is what I did: http://pastie.org/private/iagpjwaxflsya3hki8oz0w but it doesn't work. Why is that? Thank you so much Sir. Please bear with me.

Comment: please create a specific question for it as it is a different problem

Comment: Okay Sir. Just ask question about that. Thank you for all your help Sir. :) Hope you can still help me.

Answer (score 1):

Just change like this:

```
 p.load(new FileInputStream("C://Palmus-HACMS//PV//PVInfo.ini"));
```

**To load file from resource folder :**

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "PVInfo.ini";

            inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

            if (inputStream != null) {
                prop.load(inputStream);
            } else {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }
```

for more understating  see this:

http://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/

Comment: @KendallH. see ans

Comment: @KendallH. accept ans so other person can easily recognize its a correct one

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sir. But what I want to do is to not put the folder path in my code, I just want to call it in the path.properties, but it seems that it's impossible.

Comment: @KendallH. it is possible fist decide where you want to put your file ie into classpath or package or resource folder then tell me i will help to get that using only name of file

Comment: Thank you, I hope you can help me Sir. I created a resource folder the put my path.properties to it.

Comment: @KendallH. Please share directory structure and IDE name

Comment: /palmus-identify/resources/path.properties is this it Sir?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126121/discussion-between-jay-and-kendall-h).

Comment: reading `ini`file like `properties` file is a terrible practice and should never be done as it will take section names as normal keys and you will lose data if you have 2 sections with the same key

Answer (score 0):

The file you are loading in the line `property.load(fs)` on your code is the original properties file, while I assume you intended to be loading the `ini` one. You need to get the path from the original properties file and create a new file using that one.